# List from managed bean is not showing in faces datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, view-scope

I can't get a list obtained from a managed bean to show in a datatable in JSF.

When I debug it, the list has one element when it calls the method on the bean, but the page shows no elements in the datatable.

The managed bean is:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBeanMB {

    private List<MyBean> results = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
    private MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
    @EJB
    private MyBeanService myBeanService;

    public String findMyBeans() {
        results = myBeanService.findMyBeans(myBean);
        myBean = new myBeans();
        if (results != null && !results.isEmpty()) {
            return "success";
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("No results found"));
        return null;
    }
```

And the form in index.xhtml page looks like this:

```
<h:form>
            <h:messages />
            <h:outputLabel value="Nombre: " for="nombre"/>
            <h:inputText id="nombre" value="#{myBeanMB.myBean.name}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Buscar" action="#{myBeanMB.findMyBeans}" />

            <h:dataTable id="list" value="#{myBeanMB.results}" var="item">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value= "#{item.name}" />
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return `success` in your managed bean, JSF will navigate to *success.xhtml* view (this assuming you haven't set a navigation rule in *faces-config.xml* file) and the list should be handled in this view, not in *index.xhtml*. In order to *fix* your code, change your `findMyBeans` method to return `void` instead of `String`.

```
public void findMyBeans() {
    results = myBeanService.findMyBeans(myBean);
    myBean = new myBeans();
    if (results != null && !results.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("No results found"));
}
```

Comment: I do have a navigation rule for it, and it returns to index.xhtml... which is what it is supposed to do... but when it goes back to index.xhtml after returning from findMyBeans and altough results has a list with one result, it doesn't show anything in the datatable...

Comment: In other words, you haven't even tried Luiggi's answer? When you return non-null/void, then a new view will be created (whereby all view scoped beans will be recreated, including the one where you stored the results!)

Comment: Sorry it took this long to accept the answer but I couldn't try it until now :S